# Function for change value from field javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that everytime the checkbox is checked, the value of another field is changed. However whenever I declare the code: document.getElementsByName inside my function. An error is shown in debug: ReferenceError: countCheckboxes is not defined.

My checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_n1" onclick="countCheckboxes()" name="n1">
```

My function:

```
<script>
    var campo = ;
    function countCheckboxes ( ) {
        alert("teste");
        document.getElementsByName("id_qtd_numero_marcados").value="1234;"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `var campo = ;` is invalid syntax. Either specify a value (`var campo = null;`) or remove the assignment (`var campo;`). But, that error is preventing `function countCheckboxes()` from being defined.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see `getElements..` with an `s` at the end, it returns a [**nodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

A nodeList is an array-like object containing all the elements that match the selector, so to get the first element in the nodeList you'd use bracket notation, and as the nodeList is zero based, the first one would be :

```
document.getElementsByName("id_qtd_numero_marcados")[0].value = "1234;"
```

As the error you're getting is a `ReferenceError`, the function is most likely defined in a different scope, so it's not accessible when you're trying to call it, or you have errors that halts the execution of the script, and as noted in the comments, `var campo = ;` is an error, you can't declare a variable and set it's value to nothing, unless you do `var campo;`, then it would be declared, but the value would be undefined.

Comment: Ok. I change for: 
<script>
var campo = document.getElementById("id_qtd_numero_marcados");
function countCheckboxes ( ) {
      campo.value=1;
      }

    </script>
 
   but as I have to use: document.getElementById ("id_qtd_numero_marcados") within my function? I would like to increment a counter whenever a checkbox is checked.